# execute external sql script from lambda function using Python

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, psycopg2

I'm trying to execute some external SQL scripts which are containing some CREATE TABLES syntaxes while the other ones are some pre-defined PL/pgSQL functions. I'm using the Python 3.10 and the aws-psycopg2 library to create a Lambda function in AWS which will connect to a PostgreSQL AWS database and run these scripts. First, I installed the library

```
pip install aws-psycopg2 -t .
```

in my working directory.

I created a handler function:

```
import psycopg2
from psycopg2.extras import RealDictCursor
import json

# Configuration Values
endpoint_db = 'pgdatabase.xxx.amazonaws.com'
database_db = 'postgres'
username_db = 'postgres'
password_db = 'xxxxxx'
port_db = 5432

connection = psycopg2.connect(
     dbname=database_db, 
     user=username_db,
     password=password_db,
     host=endpoint_db,
     port=port_db
 )

def lambda_handler():
    cursor = connection.cursor(cursor_factory = RealDictCursor)
    cursor.execute(open("insert_clause.sql", "r").read())
    cursor.execute(open("update_table.sql", "r").read())
    # rows = cursor.fetchall()
    # json_result = json.dumps(rows)
    # print(json_result)
    # return(json_result)
    print('Done!')
    
lambda_handler()
```

The external SQL are some basic commands to the dvd_rental tables:

```
UPDATE public.category SET name = 'Horror and Thriller' WHERE category_id = 11; -- update_table.sql
INSERT INTO public.copy_actor (actor_id, first_name, last_name) VALUES (201, 'Paul', 'Newman'); -- insert_clause.sql
```

However, nothing happens when I run the handler() function first on my machine before deploying it on AWS (no tables are altered). Is there any additional setup I have to do?

Lastly, if I will manage to make these scripts working, would it be enough to include these in the zip file I'm going to upload to create the Lambda function?

Thanks!

Comment: When you say "nothing happens", are you saying that it doesn't even print `Done!`?

Comment: it is printing 'Done!' at least. But that's it.

Answer (score 1):

It was easier than  I expected; I had to commit the changes to the RDS as well using connection.commit():

```
def lambda_handler():
    cursor = connection.cursor(cursor_factory = RealDictCursor)
    
    cursor.execute(open("insert_clause.sql", "r").read())
    cursor.execute(open("update_table.sql", "r").read())

    
    # Commit changes
    connection.commit()
    
    # rows = cursor.fetchall()
    # json_result = json.dumps(rows)
    # print(json_result)
    # return(json_result)

    print('Done!')
```

Comment: Until you did `connection.commit()` there was no commit. I am not sure what *...commit the changes to the RDS...* means?

Comment: I was referring to the Amazon Relational Database Service, which is a PostgreSQL db in this instance.

Comment: Then my comment stands, this `cursor.execute()` does not commit anything until you do `connection.commit()`.  The exception being enabling [autocommit](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/connection.html#connection.autocommit) on the `connection` before you `execute` the commands.